# Did Scaramanga make love to Goodnight?

Tags: james-bond, the-man-with-the-golden-gun

It's specified that Scaramanga only kills after first making love, akin to matadors before a fight. Towards the end of the movie, he has a much-anticipated duel with Bond on his private island, while keeping a kidnapped, now-bikini-clad Goodnight in the vicinity. I can only presume he wouldn't break his tradition, and it did seem Goodnight was previously scorned by Bond more than once prior in the movie. The easy inference is she must have made love to Scaramanga the night before, but I don't recall any specific evidence to support this. Was this meant to be implied by the writers (or even Fleming himself)?